# How to update files on an apache server without restart

Tags: git, apache, deployment, web-deployment, updating

I'm using git to apply my changes to server. I already set my ssh-deployment key so with a simple command I'm updating website very easily e.g.

```
git pull
```

No problem, right? But here what happens:

If your server is used by more than 50 concurrent users, Apache will continuously *read* php / html / js... files. If a file is modified by Git and read by Apache at the same time, then Apache will fail and stuck.

Low probability but his is what happens in my situation. I tried a couple of times. I can't simply stop and resume Apache server because some users might be uploading a huge file or sending an urgent mail. So with and Apache start/stop, I can interrupt a significant process.

Do you have any solutions? What do you do for such kind of an issue?

Comment: `If a file is modified by Git and read by Apache at the same time` I don't think this can happen. Apache won't read the modified file until its finished being modified.

Comment: @arco444 thanks for the comment. Do you have any predictions why my server freezes? After update, all requests get `connection timeout` error. It works properly when I run `service apache2 restart`

Comment: @arco444: Are you sure about this?  How should Apache even know that some other process is currently writing to that file?  I can't see why Apache would get stuck this way, but I do see how this might lead to inconsistent data being loaded.  The usual work around is to export the new versions of all files to a new directory, and move the directory in place once it's ready.  Moves can be done atomically on most Unix filesystems, so this will ensure the files are always in a consistent state.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I thought modifications are done the same way you described the moves. And I'd have thought the kernel / filesystem would know not to allow a process to read changing files. That would cause all sorts of chaos. What are read/write locks for?

Comment: @arco444: Read/write locks are usually collaborative locks that are implemented completely in user space.  The filesystem doesn't (and shouldn't) provide any guarantees about the atomicity of file modifications.